# ClassNotFoundException when starting app - unable to instantiate application

Tags: android

Long story cut short - I have an app that has been around for about 4 years now with a smallish user base (around 500 devices). It was originally developed on a Win XP machine but I then migrated over to a Debian Linux setup a year or so ago. No problems, all well and good.

A few months ago I updated to the latest Android SDK / ADT for Eclipse and everything went down the pan (the appcompat-v7 wouldn't build and can't be recognised).

In frustration, I've migrated back to the XP box and all seems well and good in that I no longer get critical errors and everything builds fine. The problem is when I deploy to my Nexus 7 for testing. It installs OK but on startup I immediately get "Unfortunately, nDroid (TE) has stopped".

Logcat shows the following. The class "uk.co.beetec.android.nDroidTE.NDroidTE" extends the Android `Application` class and is quite clearly there in my code without errors or warnings at build time and it is declared in the AndroidManifest.xml.

I really have no idea what is going wrong here. Can anyone explain that stacktrace because I don't understand what might be causing it.

```
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878): Process: uk.co.beetec.android.nDroidTE, PID: 16878
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application uk.co.beetec.android.nDroidTE.NDroidTE: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "uk.co.beetec.android.nDroidTE.NDroidTE" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/uk.co.beetec.android.nDroidTE-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:563)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4526)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "uk.co.beetec.android.nDroidTE.NDroidTE" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/uk.co.beetec.android.nDroidTE-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:980)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:558)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    ... 10 more
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk.co.beetec.android.nDroidTE.NDroidTE
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):        ... 14 more
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.co.beetec.android.nDroidTE.NDroidTE
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):        ... 13 more
03-23 11:16:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(16878):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: have you added `appcompat-v7` to build path?

Comment: uk.co.beetec.android.nDroidTE.NDroidTE: is this the exact path of your application class?

Comment: I guess you have already tried to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: have you tried to migrate to Android Studio and Gradle build? Eclipse ADT is deprecated nowadays AFAIK

Comment: @hrskrs : Yep,  the Build Path looks absolutely fine and the build produces an APK of the size I'd expect (and it installs fine on my device).

Comment: @jvrodrigues : Yes, that's exactly the exact path.

Comment: @Henry : Cleaned and rebuilt several times over.

Comment: @Droidman : I haven't tried Android Studio on my XP box but I did on my Linux box after the SDK/ADT screw-up and Android Studio displayed the same behaviour although that's unrelated to this issue. The Exclipse and Android SDK/ADT setup is the same as it was a year or so ago - perhaps the migration via Git has screwed something, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have observed this error previously in the following cases:

**1.** I was using a physical device (i.e. not an emulator) that had Kitkat with ART enabled. When I ran the app on another Kitkat device with Dalvik runtime, the error seemed to have vanished.

**2.** The same problem arose due to a `.dex` build error which occurred when I shifted the SVN to another location. I deleted the old project entirely and created a new repository from the original project on my computer, and after rebuilding the project entirely the error did not reappear.

**3.** If using Eclipse with Maven, and you have enabled `multidex`, then try disabling it and building the project. If using Android Studio, set `multiDexEnabled = false`. This is a known cause of this error.

Comment: @Squonk: so, any luck ?

Comment: Not conclusive so far but it looks like your 2nd point might be relevant. It seems the Build Path was a bit screwy after I pulled the code down to the XP machine from my Git repository. I still get a fatal error at start but I now see the MAIN/LAUNCHER `Activity` and starting the app a second time works fine. I'll probably accept your answer later after a couple more tests.

Comment: @Squonk: so, any results ?

Comment: Sorry it took time, I've had a really busy few weeks. I did something similar to your point 2. I deleted the project from my Eclipse environment (but not delete the files on disk). I then cleaned up the various auto-generated project files and created a new project from the same code files.

Comment: great ... I assume that worked. When will we get a VM and a compiler that does not lead to these odd errors