# After migrating to androidx, ClassNotFound exception on android application class

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

After migrating to androidx my android application crashes on startup with the following log

```
1579308665.952 E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lezyne.gpsally, PID: 26998
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.lezyne.gpsally.LezyneLinkApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.lezyne.gpsally.LezyneLinkApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lezyne.gpsally-39sfIUY5mcmCi0Ff5YTHOw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lezyne.gpsally-39sfIUY5mcmCi0Ff5YTHOw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.lezyne.gpsally-39sfIUY5mcmCi0Ff5YTHOw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:971)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5796)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6572)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.lezyne.gpsally.LezyneLinkApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lezyne.gpsally-39sfIUY5mcmCi0Ff5YTHOw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lezyne.gpsally-39sfIUY5mcmCi0Ff5YTHOw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.lezyne.gpsally-39sfIUY5mcmCi0Ff5YTHOw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:965)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5796) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6572) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.lezyne.gpsally-39sfIUY5mcmCi0Ff5YTHOw==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.lezyne.gpsally-39sfIUY5mcmCi0Ff5YTHOw==/base.apk': Bad method handle type 7
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:676)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:709)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:936)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2242)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5703)
            ... 8 more
```

My gradle dependancies is as follows:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation fileTree(dir: "src/main/jniLibs", include: '*.so')
implementation fileTree(dir: "lib", include: '*.so')

apply plugin: 'findbugs'
implementation project(':android-crop')

implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'


implementation 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.+'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.8.2'
implementation 'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'


implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
implementation 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'

implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'

implementation 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.5.1'

implementation 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1'

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.24.0'
implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'

implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'

implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0'

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
```

The application tag of my manifest looks like

```
<application
    android:name=".LezyneLinkApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

The problem appears to be the same one that this question is about [Application class not found after upgrading to Android X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096026/application-class-not-found-after-upgrading-to-android-x)  The comments suggest clean build and invalidate cache, and this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54024154/1247248 indicated manually deleting the build folders. Unfortunately none of those things worked.

I also found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29210004/1247248 so I tried turning off multiDex and bumping up my minSdk to 26.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

----- EDIT ----

1, Yes I did try invalidating caches and restarting.

The application class is defined as

```
package com.lezyne.gpsally;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.lezyne.gpsally.api.requests.rides.GetRidesListApiRequest;
import com.lezyne.gpsally.tools.RoutingProfile;
import com.lezyne.gpsally.tools.Settings;
import com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import net.danlew.android.joda.JodaTimeAndroid;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import lezyne.com.gpsally.sql.DaoMaster;
import lezyne.com.gpsally.sql.DaoSession;
import lezyne.com.gpsally.sql.PlaceDao;
import lezyne.com.gpsally.sql.PlaceSearchKeyDao;
import lezyne.com.gpsally.sql.SqlRideDao;
import lezyne.com.gpsally.sql.SqlStravaAthleteDao;
import lezyne.com.gpsally.sql.SqlStravaSegmentDao;



public class LezyneLinkApplication extends Application {

private static WeakReference<Context> mContext;
public boolean hasShownFirmwarePopup = false;

public static String resourceString(int id)
{
    return mContext.get().getString(id);
}

static public final boolean isMonkeyTestBuild=false;
static public boolean helpScreenShowing=false;

public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
    GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
    ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
}

public static Typeface customFontTypeface;
private DaoSession daoSession;
public RequestQueue requestQue;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Picasso picasso;

private void copyFromAssets(String name)
{
    try {
        //Also get the font file
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(),name);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(name);
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int bufferLength = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        fileOutput.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void copyFromAssets(String name, String dir)
{
    try {
        //Also get the font file
        File dirFile = new File(getFilesDir(),dir);
        dirFile.mkdir();
        File file = new File(dirFile,name);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(dir+"/"+name);
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int bufferLength = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        fileOutput.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    mContext = new WeakReference<Context>(getApplicationContext());
    JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);
    setupDatabase();


    ArrayList<RoutingProfile> profiles = RoutingProfile.loadRoutingProfiles(this);
    for (RoutingProfile profile : profiles)
    {
        copyFromAssets(profile.xmlFile,"USA");
        copyFromAssets(profile.xmlFile,"Germany");
        copyFromAssets(profile.xmlFile,"Japan");
        copyFromAssets(profile.xmlFile,"UK");
    }
    copyFromAssets("2593-UnDotum.ttf");
    copyFromAssets("osm-style.xml");


    requestQue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQue,new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            mCache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return mCache.get(url);
        }
    });

    GetRidesListApiRequest.syncRides(this,new GetRidesListApiRequest.SyncCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void fail(boolean invalidPassword) {
            //TODO: Initiate retry logic if the first load fails
        }

        @Override
        public void success() {

        }
    });

    File userDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),"LezyneGpsAlly/route");
    userDir.mkdirs();
    Settings settings = new Settings(this);
    userDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),"LezyneGpsAlly/"+settings.username());
    userDir.mkdirs();

    picasso = new Picasso
            .Builder(this)
            .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(getFilesDir()
                    ,10000000))//10,000,000 10 Meg image cache
            .build();


    overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SERIF", "Helvetica.ttf"); // font from assets: "assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
    overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "DEFAULT", "Helvetica.ttf"); // font from assets: "assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
    overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SANS_SERIF", "Helvetica.ttf"); // font from assets: "assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
    overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "MONOSPACE", "Helvetica.ttf"); // font from assets: "assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf


}

public static Picasso picasso(Context context){
    LezyneLinkApplication self = (LezyneLinkApplication)context.getApplicationContext();
    return self.picasso;
}

private void setupDatabase() {
    try {
        DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "lezyne-db2", null);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
        daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
    } catch (RuntimeException e)
    {
        File file = new File("lezyne-db2");
        file.delete();
        DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "lezyne-db2", null);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
        daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
    }
}

public DaoSession getDaoSession() {
    return daoSession;
}

public static SqlRideDao getSqlRideDao(Context context) {
    return ((LezyneLinkApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getDaoSession().getSqlRideDao();
}

public static SqlStravaAthleteDao getStravaAthleteDao(Context context) {
    return ((LezyneLinkApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getDaoSession().getSqlStravaAthleteDao();
}

public static SqlStravaSegmentDao getStravaSegmentDao(Context context) {
    return ((LezyneLinkApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getDaoSession().getSqlStravaSegmentDao();
}

public static PlaceDao getPlaceDao(Context context) {
    return ((LezyneLinkApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getDaoSession().getPlaceDao();
}

public static PlaceSearchKeyDao getPlaceSearchKeyDao(Context context) {
    return ((LezyneLinkApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getDaoSession().getPlaceSearchKeyDao();
}


/**
 * Using reflection to override default typeface
 * NOTICE: DO NOT FORGET TO SET TYPEFACE FOR APP THEME AS DEFAULT TYPEFACE WHICH WILL BE OVERRIDDEN
 * @param context to work with assets
 * @param defaultFontNameToOverride for example "monospace"
 * @param customFontFileNameInAssets file name of the font from assets
 */
public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
    try {
        customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);

        final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     //   Log.e("Can not set custom font " + customFontFileNameInAssets + " instead of " + defaultFontNameToOverride);
    }
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);

}

}
```

--- EDIT ---

I finally got this to work by following the instructions in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/50983181/1247248 it had to do with Java 8

Comment: Needs more info, such as whether the application class in question exists in said package.

Comment: Did you tried by invalidating caches & restarting the studio?